# Getting milliseconds from the date, but showing one day less than actual

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I'm trying to print milliseconds from date in python, I used below code to get millisecond since I'm new to Python I would like to check with someone here if this is that right way of getting milliseconds:

```
import datetime

def findmili(date):
    return int(date.strftime("%s")) * 1000
x = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/27/2017',  "%m/%d/%Y")
print findmili(x)
```

Can someone please help me to validate this, if this is not right way of getting can you tell what's the exact way of getting this in python.

Looks like something wrong, I'm trying to get millisecond of `Jan 12 2017` but my program returns this value: `1484179200000`. If I convert those milliseconds to a date using [this online utility](http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/#.Wf6GH7aZPdQ), it shows `Jan 11 2017` instead of `Jan 12 2017`.

**Note:** I have to use Python 2.7 version only. `:(`

Comment: if you're new to python PLEASE consider using Python3

Comment: @0TTT0 Most Python books have Python 2.x as it's version even Python 3.x already came out.

Comment: @BryanZeng that's just not true. even O'Reilly books are 3.x

Comment: Looks like something wrong, I'm trying to get millisecond of Jan 12 2017 but my program returns this value 1484179200000. If I covert my millisecond to date using this online utility it shows Jan 11 2017 instead of Jan 12 2017. http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/#.Wf6GH7aZPdQ

Comment: I don't understand. There's no millisecond part to '01/12/2017' because that's a date.

Comment: @BillBell -My input will come as date only, that I'm converting as millisecond. Still if millisecond is not there why its calculating one day less than actual date?

Comment: @0TTT0 Sorry, I didn't realize that until now. I read books from my local library and most books there are Python 2. I forgot the current release is already up to 3.6.3

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I believe a bit of clarification in your question would be to indicate that you are looking for milliseconds that have elapsed from epoch till the date you provide as that is what the tool seems to be doing.

A simple way to do something like that is like this :

```
int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%s")) * 1000
```

replace `datetime.datetime.now()` with your own datetime object. So the completed function might be something like this :

```
import datetime

def findmili(date):
    return int(date.strftime("%s")) * 1000
x = datetime.datetime.strptime('10Nov2017', '%d%b%Y')
print findmili(x)
```

As an aside, your code won't actually run in python2.7. This is because, you have made an error in line 6 where instead of `d = datetime.strptime(myDate, "%m/%d/%Y")`, it should actually be `d = datetime.datetime.strptime(myDate, "%m/%d/%Y")`

Another aside, your code is also correct ( except from the error above ) . Its returning `1484150400000` which returns as `Thu Jan 12 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800`.

Comment: I update my code as per your suggestion - see my recent edit in post. but I'm still getting millisecond of Jan 26 2017 not for Jan 27 2017. What's wrong in my code? Please help

Comment: You are most likely using the incorrect timezone in the utility. Please use GMT and you should get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

When you use that online site notice that its result depends on where the site *believes* that you are situated. In the time zone where I live (Eastern Canada) I get the correct result. However, if I change the timezone on the site to the one for Phoenix, Arizona in the United States, for instance, this is the result.

[image]

I suspect that this is why you are getting an unexpected result.